# Add conda to path in fish

Tags: fish, conda

```
~> conda install pandas
fish: Unknown command 'conda'
```

I understand that I need to add `conda` to PATH, but no matter what combinations of commands I tried, I could get it to work. I still get the above error.

Answer (score 43):

1. Install [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com)
2. Run `conda init fish`
3. In your `~/.config/fish/config.fish` you should see some lines added by Anaconda:

   ```
    #>>> conda initialize >>>
    # !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
    eval your/path/to/anaconda3/bin/conda "shell.fish" "hook" $argv | source
    # <<< conda initialize <<<
   ```
4. Restart the terminal. You should see now Anaconda activating the `(base)` environment. Check running `echo $CONDA_PREFIX` the loaded environment is pointing in the right place.

Hope this helps. Let us know if you still have problems

Comment: Since the `conda` command wasn't in `PATH` you'll maybe have to execute conda with it's full path. It can for example be found by `which conda`.

For me it was at `/opt/anaconda/bin/conda` or at `/opt/anaconda/condabin/conda`.

Comment: As of now, conda init fish prevents fish from opening.

Answer (score 36):

Where is `conda` installed? If it's in `~/anaconda/bin`, then you want to run this:

Try `set -U fish_user_paths ~/anaconda/bin $fish_user_paths`

Modifying PATH is discussed in [the fish tutorial](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#tut_path)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 18):

you can do it in one Line and don't bother yourself (MacOS and Linux)

```
/(your conda installation path)/bin/conda init fish
```

your condo installation usually in '/Users/- your UserName -/anaconda3'

if someone want to know about install fish, best way is Homebrew.
after `brew install fish` you mush add fish to supportable shells in `/etc/shells`.
and then with `chsh` change default shell to `fish`.
if it's not clear ask in comment!

Answer (score 5):

I assume you have 'config.fish'(create if you don't have) file in ~/.config/fish/ directory.
Now add the following to the file 'config.fish':

```
set  PATH /home/<user>/anaconda3/bin $PATH
```

Then **save** the file. **Close the current terminal (*fish shell*) and open again.**
Now you can use Anaconda's python.

To check: run `python3` and you will see:

```
 Python 3.7.1 (default, Dec 14 2018, 19:28:38)
 [GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

To use `conda activate env` command

Enter this command on your **fish shell**:

```
conda init fish
```

Now, restart the terminal and use any conda command you like.

Answer (score 2):

Conda command will not work until you run the conda init fish. but on fish terminal it will also not work.

1. Open Fish/bash terminal

## it will open the bash inside fish, incase you opened fish

```sh
$ bash
```

2. then init the conda

```sh
conda init fish
```

You are done

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed `conda` prior to installing `fish`, you most likely installed it using `zsh` which comes as default since macOS Catalina. In this case you do *not* need to reinstall `conda`, simply switch back to the `zsh` shell, like so:

```bash
zsh
```

then init conda from zsh

```bash
conda init fish
```

Then you can go ahead and open a new terminal window. If the fish shell is automatically opening, you should be able to use the `conda` command.

To verify, type

```bash
which conda
```

and if it's available, you should see the path to the installation.

Answer (score 0):

If running `conda init fish` prevents `fish` from running (as it did for me), it would be better to just remove whatever conda has added to the `~/.config/fish/config.fish` file and just add the following line.

```
source /Users/yourname/anaconda3/etc/fish/conf.d/conda.fish
```

assuming Anaconda is installed in `/Users/yourname/`